# The panels keep disappearing when I change the layout (GUI designing in NetBeans)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, layout-manager

I'm trying to make a small application but I'm new at GUI designing in Java. I'm working in NetBeans 8.0.2 and every time I change the layout of `JPanel`  it disappears. I can still see it at the navigator and edit it from there but I can't see it either on the Preview Design or in the Running of the Project itself, so basically all I can see is the frame or the panel that contains the other panels.

I'm not sure if its because of the relations of layouts to each other, I tried with different combinations of layouts and they always disappears.

This is what i'm trying to make:

A panel from wich to make queries into the database and show them in a table
http://s3.postimg.org/moyn0zxdv/historial.jpg

and a panel that shows user activity on the page
http://s23.postimg.org/bbyilunvv/actividad.jpg

there's more panels than that but all the program has this same design: menu bar in the top, a search box and a button and the panels in the center that show various content

This is my code:

```
public class NewJFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public NewJFrame2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        ROJO = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        AMARILLO = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 204, 255));

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 255, 51));
        jPanel3.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        ROJO.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
        ROJO.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        AMARILLO.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 102));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout AMARILLOLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(AMARILLO);
        AMARILLO.setLayout(AMARILLOLayout);
        AMARILLOLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            AMARILLOLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        AMARILLOLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            AMARILLOLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        ROJO.add(AMARILLO, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(140, 140, 140)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 171, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                        .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                        .addComponent(ROJO, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(196, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(ROJO, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(312, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel AMARILLO;
    private javax.swing.JPanel ROJO;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: Is it visible when you use Free Design?

Comment: yes but i want to use border layout on a panel and then add several panels to it in card layout mode but if i change the layout from the default FlowLayout the pannels dissapear

Comment: BTW - which panel is disappearing?

Comment: i setted ROJO to borderLayout and it dissapeared leaving only AMARILLO visible, i had this trouble with another sample of code, it only works when i leave everything FlowLayout wich is not useful to me

Comment: If your question is about the usage of a GUI builder then you need to edit the tags and make it clear in the question title and content. If your question is for help on designing a GUI, then show (make a picture in MS Paint or something) what you want to get.